# How to report on dynamic emails with impression region dynamic contents and get metrics on each dynamic region

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, email-studio, email-tracking, datorama

**Background:** In our use-case, each email campaign includes different categories of customers. Originally, we used to have multiple emails coded /per email campaigns like:

- EmailContentFile1_CustType1
- EmailContentFile2_CustType2
- EmailContentFile3_CustType3

**Challenge:** Original approach of hardcoding emails based on each category within each email campaign was hard to maintain.

**Moved to a newer DYNAMIC approach:** We moved to a dynamic approach where within audience (data extension), we will have a field that determines the customer type and we will have multiple dynamic content regions within each email (with the use of Impression regions).

- This dynamic approach works great and we only have to produce one final email content file with dynamic region content blocks in it.

**Reporting challenge:** With the new approach, we get a reporting challenge since we can get metrics for the email as one but if we want to get breakdown of each dynamic region content block, like opens, clicks, unsubs, etc, there is no way to get that. There is an analytics report for impression region but it is limited and needs to be run for each jobid.

Even Datorama does not support impression regions.

Reporting on dynamic emails involve writing custom sql scripts which we want to avoid, if possible  since we have way too many campaigns and this is not a scalable solution.

**Question:** Is there any way to get metrics for each dynamic content region? Is this a common challenge of using dynamic content block that is faced by everyone? How everyone else is solving for this?